# Determine if the following is a subspace and find its smallest possible subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, span

$U_k = \{(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} \in \mathbb{R}^n\ |\ x_k = 0\}$. 
Is this a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?
For $n = 3$, what is the smallest vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contains $U_1, U_2, U_3$.

Apparently only $2$ vectors are needed to span this. And the smallest subspace is $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself. What does that mean?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\mathbb R^n|x_k = 0$?

Comment: @WilliamStagner: that is common in set notation to mean the set of $x\in\Bbb R^n$ such that the $k^{\text{th}}$ coordinate is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove directly that $U_k$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ or use that $U_k$ is the kernel of the linear form
$$\varphi_k\colon \Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R,\; (x_i)_{1\le i\le n}\mapsto x_k$$

Notice that $U_k$ is an hyper-plan and the smallest subspace that contains two different hyper-plans is the whole space.